# Help with routing (/:name/:named_param)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, url-routing

Im stuck in cakephp routing.

I want to redirect "/coches/mustang-100/" to "cars" model with "display" view.

I'm trying with this, but it redirects me to "cars" "index" view:

```
Router::connect('/:coches/:modelo_coche/',
    array('controller' => 'cars', 'action' => 'display'),
    array('pass' => array('modelo_coche'),'coches' => 'coches')
);
```

I want to: www.myweb.com/coches/mustang-100/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got your needs right, please try if this one matches what you want:

```
Router::connect('/coches/:modelo_coche', array('controller' => 'cars', 'action' => 'display'), array('pass' => array('modelo_coche')));
```

Comment: Ok. Its works in both forms. Was my mistake but in display function, i've a redirect action. Thanks you and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the answer but I don't have the rep to comment on your question yet.

But, can you put a trailing slash on the end of a route like that?

I've never seen routing done with slashes at the end so this *could* be the problem here.